# Creating Table in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a table in Tableau in following format:

[image]

Rather than this format:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to convert Father Cell to Program?

Comment: Not actually. Want to the change the structure of the table as mentioned.

Comment: do you mean just transposing the view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only the view.

Comment: then simply transpose it.  `ctrl + w` on windows or through menu

Comment: Actually, I did that. Its not transpose that I want. Could you please have a look at first table above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222955/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-pardeep-kumar).